# OS X client for Trello that supports keyboard shortcut to create new card

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts, trello

I want to optimize the task of creating a new Trello card for a specific board and list. Lots of tools exist for creating cards from a different piece of media (bookmarklet for web, incoming email, iOS share sheet, etc.), but I need to create cards from scratch.

To achieve this, I am looking for an OS X app that acts as a client for Trello, and can sit in the background/menubar waiting for a global keyboard shortcut. Upon activating this shortcut, the user should be presented with a text field for at least the card title, and the ability to use the keyboard to save as a new card to a predetermined list.

I have already tested all of the free apps in the Mac App Store (that result from searching "Trello"), and they do not have this capability. Before I buy one of the paid options, I'd like to know which (if any), provide this.

Comment: Sounds like you need [KeyboardMaestro](http://www.KeyboardMaestro.com).
This can use keyboard shortcuts, ask for text input, assign it to a variable and so on.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to avoid having to write my own Trello API calls. In order for a Macro to work it would have to invoke the entire Trello web UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that [Pomello](http://www.tinynudge.co/pomello/), a tool I was already using, can actually do this. It has a minimal interface, so the required command-tab to it isn't too bad, and then fully supports keyboard entry of new cards and board/list assignment.

Pomello is a chrome app that runs in Google Chrome and Chromium.